# Change CSS of ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: css, angular, sass, dropdown

i have not used this module much so having very little knowledge.
I am having a very strange issue of multi select drop down is going over the header I found the solution for this is to change the z-index of it but can do it, below I have shared my css code

```
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-list {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #959595;
}
```

this shows when i inspect it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkuqY.png)

Comment: Please provide the header code also your dropdown

Comment: .multiselect-dropdown[_ngcontent-mfl-c126] .dropdown-btn[_ngcontent-mfl-c126] {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.52857143;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

Comment: Please add your code to your question as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), not in the comment section. You can add it to your question by clicking Edit, just below your question's tags.

Comment: @Thomas already added it

Comment: Thank for adding your CSS code, but it would be better if you could share a [mcve].